# TestStack White cannot setValue to OpenFileDialog's ToolStrip

Tags: c#, .net, automation

I want to change folder path to an OpenFileDialog.
[image: OpenFileDialog ToolStrip]

the tool strip properties are

```
ToolStrip. AutomationId:1001, Name:位址: C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\理想国\Picture, ControlType:工具列, FrameworkId:Win32
```

I use

```
ToolStrip ts =  window.GetToolStrip("1001");
ts.SetValue(@"C:\");
```

ts I got is correct item, my program can move mouse to hover the Item but I just can't SetValue or Enter to it.

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        IUIItem a = window.Get(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("Item 202"));
```

[image: Button]

click this button first

```
a.Click();
```

then use SendKeys.SendWait(value);

```
SendKeys.SendWait(paths.ElementAt(0));
```

Last step, KeyIn "Return"

```
window.KeyIn(KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.RETURN);
```

[image: OpenFileDialog changed]

Done.